# Launcher in 13.04 does not always show when mouse touches the edge of the screen

Tags: unity, launcher, mouse, autohide

I have a weird problem with the launcher ever since I upgraded from 12.04 to 13.04.

I've set the launcher to auto-hide mode and whenever the pointer touched the left edge of the screen the launcher would pop out as expected. After upgrading to 13.04 the launcher sometimes fails to respond. I've tweaked some parameters like sensitivity, acceleration etc through CompizConfig but they don't seem to change anything.

What is troubling me is that this behavior seems to be completely random. Sometimes it happens when there is a window attached to the side, sometimes not. Even when it fails to appear the first time, if I try again and again, it will eventually appear. Touching the top left corner of the screen with the mouse always shows the launcher. Also, to make things even more random, it seems to me that the launcher usually fails to appear when i'm using my bluetooth mouse. When this happens, I try my laptop's trackpad, which doesn't seem to help, but the red dot (I'm on an IBM Thinkpad) almost always works.

If anyone has any idea at all, please share. It's not a huge problem, but its randomness and lack of apparent explanation drives me mad. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I think i figured out what was going on. One of the settings in ConfigCompiz was Duration of Sticky Edge Release After Break, which didn't sound relevant at first, so I hadn't tweaked it. It was originally set to 1000, I set it to 0, which I think solved the problem.